# How to create arabic character class in MySQL using RegExp?

Tags: mysql, regex, arabic

For example I want to create a class character, ara digit `[٩-٠]` .. content all digits.
The corresponding Unicode is `[U+0660-U+0669]`, I tried this:

```
Select * FROM employees WHERE ID REGEXP [\u{0660}-\u{0669}];
```

I get this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[\u{0660}-\u{0669}] LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1"

Comment: What flavor are you using?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: You need to put the regular expression in single quotes as a string literal.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm new in this forum and i have just starting mysql, my problems is :i have a set of unicode characters wich i want to exclude on my search for example [ÀÂÃÄÄÆ.......ÔÕÖ] i just do this [the first char - the last char] c ie :[À-Ö] and it works perfectly with mysql query.

Comment: but if i use arabic charactere eg: Select * FROM employees WHERE LastName REGEXP '[ا-ب]'; i get this error messge: Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "REGEXP" at position 39)
Unexpected token. (near "'[ا-ب]'" at position 46)
SQL query: Documentation

Select * FROM employees WHERE LastName REGEXP '[ا-ب]' LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'regexp'

Comment: Is `ID`'s characer set latin1? You should update the question with the new errors and code..

Comment: Arabic _cannot_ be represented in latin1.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE employees` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html says

> Warning
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are
>   not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte
>   character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by
>   their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal
>   even if a given collation treats them as equal.

That is, if you use `Ã` in a regexp, it will treat the 2-byte utf8 code as 2 bytes (in hex) `C3` and `83`.  If this gives you the 'right' answer, it will be more by 'luck' than design.

This does work:

```
mysql> SELECT '١' REGEXP '[٩-٠]';
+-----------------------+
| '١' REGEXP '[٩-٠]'    |
+-----------------------+
|                     1 |
+-----------------------+
```

But, it is just coincidence.  The regexp is something like `[x0-x9]` where x is the D9 byte, 0 is A0 and 9 is A9.  But then the regexp is "any character `x`, or between `0` and `x`, or `9`, which is not what you wanted.

This *might* work for 'all' of Arabic:  `REGEXP UNHEX('5BD82DDD5D')`, but only because 'all' start with hex D8 through DD.  (However, there may be other things in that range.)  Furthermore, that will only check "Does the string contain an Arabic letter; it cannot used for anything more complex, such as phrases or a subset of letters.

Back to the digit range.  Just checking for hex `D9` is not safe, because that will include percent sign, superscript letters, and other characters.  This *may* work:  `REGEXP UNHEX('D95BA02DA95D')`.

Caveat:  Most of what I have said in this answer is untested; I'm inventing a solution in an area where I have no experience (REGEXP with utf8).

Comment: i have tested this example:  CREATE TABLE namTst
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO namTst
(ID, Name)
VALUES
(NULL, 'Smith'),
(NULL, 'Ýrmada'),
(NULL, 'Schmidt'),
(NULL, 'Clingon'),
(NULL, 'Dalek'),
(NULL, 'Bush'),
(NULL, 'Burns'),
(NULL, 'Builth'),
(NULL, 'Thomas');

Comment: SELECT * FROM `namtst` WHERE Name REGEXP '[À-Õ]'; the query return the line that containt ''Ý", despite Ý is out of set '[À-Õ]'.

Comment: Include some strings that you want to catch; I think they will be skipped, too.  Bottom line: It is not going to work.

Comment: i found this http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html. 'the quivalence class'  but how i can use it on mysql.

Comment: and i found this :[=character_class=]
An equivalence class, standing for the sequences of characters of all collating elements equivalent to that one, including itself. For example, if o and (+) are the members of an equivalence class, then [[=o=]], [[=(+)=]], and [o(+)] are all synonymous. An equivalence class may not be an endpoint of a range. but no example to explain this

Comment: The underlying problem is that MySQL's `REGEXP` only looks at _bytes_, not _characters_.  As I said, the _character_ `Ã (and all Arabic characters)` is composed of 2 _bytes_.